# Why foreach could not be used with String?

Tags: java

I am trying something like

```
String s = "test string";
for(Character c: s) {

}
```

The compiler reports error.  I am wondering the reason why I could not use foreach with String?

Comment: `String` is not an array nor Iterable. You can iterate over `s.toCharArray()`.

Comment: @shmosel, that should be an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is set out in [JLS 14.14.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2):

> ```
> EnhancedForStatement:
>     for ( {VariableModifier} LocalVariableType VariableDeclaratorId : Expression ) Statement
> ```
>
> ...
>
> The type of the `Expression` must be a subtype of the raw type `Iterable` or an array type (§10.1), or a compile-time error occurs.

A `String` is not a subtype of `Iterable` or an array type.  Therefore .... compilation error.

---

As @shmosel mentions, you can iterate over the `char[]` returned by `s.toCharArray()`.  However, that will create a new array<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - ... unless your JVMs JIT compiler is smart enough to optimize that away.  I don't think they currently can do that, and I wouldn't bet on the Java designers wanting to implement that optimization.</sup>

Comment: It would be kind of cool if in some future release of Java, `String` was made to `implements Iterable<Character>`.

Comment: I'd like to see JIT optimization of `Character` to `char` first.